# Not enough arguments for format string python

Tags: python, codacy

On codacy it detects an issue where I dont have enough arguments for format string. Help please.

code:

```
self.notify.error("An item we don't have: track %s level %s was selected." % [track, level])
```

Comment: You might find str.format less error prone `"An item we don't have: track {} level {} was selected.".format(track, level)`

Comment: thanks ill try using that :)

Comment: post this is as an answer and ill mark it as resolved if it fixes it :)

Comment: It will definitely work I  just added an example using str.format as it is the preferred way in python to format strings and much more feature-full than the old style formatting.

Comment: well this is correct solution so please post as an answer thank you :)

Comment: @Mgracre, post the answer that worked and you can accept your own and get the rep ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass a tuple, not a list

```
self.notify.error("An item we don't have: track %s level %s was selected." % (track, level))
```

Comment: Or, if `.error()` is a logging function, omit the tuple altogether and just pass the arguments directly: `self.notify.error("An item we don't have: track %s level %s was selected.", track, level)`

Answer (score 2):

this is how i fixed it

```
"An item we don't have: track {} level {} was selected.".format(track, level)
```

Comment: does anyone agree the 2 day wait makes no sense to accept your own answer?

Comment: While this is the preferred way of formatting strings nowadays, this doesn't answer the question as to why you were getting the error in the first place. The first answer does this well. Hence the two day waiting period: you might have a fix, but do you have an answer?